# Firebase entitiy model to get all data from dataSnapshot

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

```
"SubjectList" : {
"10MAT31" : {
  "examMarks" : "100",
  "iaMarks" : "25",
  "name" : "Engineering Mathematics - III",
  "partA" : {
    "part" : "Part A",
    "units" : {
      "unit1" : {
        "topics" : {
          "topic1" : "Curve fitting by the method of least squares- Fitting of curves of the form \\(y=ax+b\\), \\(y=ax^2+bx+c\\), \\(y=ae^{bx}\\).",
          "topic2" : "Optimization: Linear programming, mathematical formulation of linear programming problem (LPP), Graphical method and simplex method."
        },
        "unit" : "Unit 1",
        "unitHours" : "7",
        "unitName" : "FOURIER SERIES"
      }
    }
  },
  "partB" : {
    "part" : "Part B",
    "units" : {
      "unit5" : {
        "topics" : {
          "topic1" : "Convergence and divergence of infinite series of positive terms, definition and illustrative examples*.",
          "topic2" : "Periodic functions, Dirichlet's conditions, Fourier series of periodic functions of period 2π and arbitrary period, half range Fourier series.",
          "topic3" : "Complex form of Fourier Series.",
          "topic4" : "Practical harmonic analysis."
        },
        "unit" : "Unit 5",
        "unitHours" : 6,
        "unitName" : "FOURIER TRANSFORMS"
      }
    }
  },
  "subjectCode" : "10MAT31"
}
```

}

If I add a `valueEventListener` to `SubjectList` node, how can I model my class to get all the details from `dataSnapshot` ? Or, how `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` can be used to display the data in `RecyclerView`. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Did you try anything already? Aside from that: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: I have attached the JSON code as suggested.